# Unfair to ask for food comp as we are going through coronavirus?

Tags: compensation, europe

When working from office we had free lunches. Because of coronavirus we're working from home.

Today I asked my manager if I can have food compensation now that the office is closed. He says he'd check if feasible.

My country is on a lockdown and that has effect on the economy of course.

Considering the current situation and that we are **all** going through this (companies included): how *unfair* to my company my request has been?

**EDIT**: To add more context, in my country is pretty common to have the companies pay for your lunch from Monday to Friday (I don't think it's mandatory for them though).

Comment: Not unfair. But personally, if I can manage without, I wouldn't ask.

Comment: This feels petty.

Comment: "fairness" seems like an arbitrary thing to ask us to decide for you. I'm sorry you're in such a tough situation, but I'm not sure if this question is really fitting for the guidelines here. Maybe you can check out [the help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help) and make some edits to keep this on topic.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere He says he'd check if feasible

Comment: How good and/or costly is the food you are missing? Is it a buttered bread and water or more of a five course meal?

Comment: Also, please add a country tag, since there are huge differences between countries. Does your employer *have* to let you work from home at full pay? Or is it a courtesy?

Comment: Is your industry very affected by ths virus (hotel etc.)? Can you afford the food yourself?

Comment: You'd be wise to avoid thinking about this as an issue of fairness, or justice, or entitlement.

Comment: @O.Jones, could you elaborate further please?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not *unfair* to ask, but I don't think you'll get very far. Free lunches are a perk, which are loosely defined as "nice-to-have" things that a company provides. These are distinct from benefits, which are forms non-wage compensation like paid time off or health insurance. A company is not required to continue to provide perks, and it might seem petty to ask about something like this at a time when both employers and employees are in a difficult situation. Many offices offer free coffee to their employees, but that doesn't mean they'll start handing out Starbucks gift cards to people who are working remotely.

Comment: I would add a bit on an explanation of why it seems petty. For example, the company is already accepting that productivity will be lower (it will be unless you are already doing a lot of WFH anyway), and not expecting employees to be paid less, or work less hours, etc, so to on top of that want monetary compensation will make it look... not so great. Gotta play with the team.

Answer (score 6):

Whether it's "Fair" depends on whether you and your employer are making similar sacrifices for comparable benefits.

Hopefully everyone gets a reduced chance of falling ill, a higher chance of receiving medical help if you need it, and a lower chance that people you care about might die.

They accept reduced productivity, and hope to avoid large numbers of people being unable to work at the same time, which might lead to a disaster.

You sacrifice your free lunch, but save on commuting time and cost, and possibly have a more relaxed time working at home.

I'd say it's more than a fair exchange already, and wouldn't ask for more unless the cost of making a sandwich will leave you unable to pay the bills.

Answer (score 5):

If you ask for this you will be giving your manager/company the impression that this is your priority during a crisis. I wouldn't do that unless you absolutely need to.

Comment: Eating is a huge priority if you want to live past a week.

Comment: @Dan If this is your only way of getting food then definitely ask. Otherwise it is a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

> Considering the current situation and that we are all going through this (companies included): how unfair my request has been?

In the context of an employee working for a company I don't think it's an **unfair** request. **Unreasonable** and slightly **insulting** yes but not an unfair request.

If you mean society in general then our society is generally unfair.

Personally unless my livelihood depended on it I would not ask this as you will find the reaction to be bad. I'm close to 100% sure that you will not get any money for food whilst working from home.

Comment: How is this _insulting_?

Comment: @pharmaqui This is an extraordinary situation. It's a global pandemic he likes of which we have never before seen in our lifetimes. Stock markets around the globe are crashing. Companies are going bust. People are losing their jobs. People are dying. So to ask for your lunch to be comped whilst you work from home is extremely insulting. If I were your manager you'd be getting a serious dressing down for even suggesting this. You'll save more not having to commute.